# Pandas Series: selecting index of highest value in a day?

Tags: python, pandas

Given a timeseries where each day has several entries at different times, and each time has a value:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
ts1 = pd.Series([1, 2, 4, 3],
                 index=[datetime(2011,1,2,1,1,1),   # first day
                        datetime(2011,1,2,2,2,2),
                        datetime(2011,1,3,1,1,1),   # second day
                        datetime(2011,1,3,4,4,4)])
```

How do I iterate over this series such that I get one index for each date, with that index corresponding to the highest value for that date?

For the above example, I would like the iteration to cover these values:

```
datetime(2011,1,2,2,2,2)   # highest value on 2011-1-2 is 2
datetime(2011,1,3,1,1,1)   # highest value on 2011-1-3 is 4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `groupby.max`, using a `pd.Grouper` object with a frequency of 'D' for days.

```
ts1.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D')).max()

2011-01-02    2
2011-01-03    4
Freq: D, dtype: int64
```

Or, `floor` the index before grouping—

```
ts1.groupby(ts1.index.floor('D')).max()

2011-01-02    2
2011-01-03    4
dtype: int64
```

Or lastly, query `date` from the index—

```
ts1.groupby(ts1.index.date).max()

2011-01-02    2
2011-01-03    4
dtype: int64
```

If you're doing this with a `Series` rather an `Index`, you will need to call these functions through the `.dt` accessor.

---

If you want the max value *with* the index, use `idxmax` instead and then index `ts1` with loc—

```
ts1.loc[ts1.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D')).idxmax()]

2011-01-02 02:02:02    2
2011-01-03 01:01:01    4
dtype: int64
```

Comment: This is close... can I get the full timestamp?  I need it to index another series.

Comment: @MarkHarrison Very much! Use `idxmax` instead, and do an additional indexing operation. I've edited to show you.

Answer (score 1):

Let us try `duplicated`

```
ts1=ts1.sort_values()
ts1[ts1.index.astype(str).str[:10].duplicated()]
Out[381]: 
2011-01-02 02:02:02    2
2011-01-03 01:01:01    4
dtype: int64
```